# Mutually Exclusive Toggle Behavior for Segments in UISegmentedContol

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uisegmentedcontrol

Is it possible to deselect a segment of the `UISegmentedControl` by tapping it the second time? I am currently using a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` object to `setSelectedSegmentIndex` to `UISegmentedControlNoSegment`. However, I'd rather have the selected segment deselect on the second tap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another method is to subclass the `UISegmentedControl`. For example:

```
@interface ToggleSegmentedControl : UISegmentedControl
{
   NSUInteger selectedSegment;
}

@end


@implementation ToggleSegmentedControl

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
{
   if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame])
   {
      selectedSegment = self.selectedSegmentIndex;
   }
   return self;
}

-(void)awakeFromNib 
{
  selectedSegment = self.selectedSegmentIndex;
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

   if( selectedSegment == self.selectedSegmentIndex && selectedSegment!=-1)
   {
     self.selectedSegmentIndex= UISegmentedControlNoSegment; 
     selectedSegment=-1; 
   } 
   else 
  { 
    selectedSegment=self.selectedSegmentIndex;
  }

}

@end
```

The above code may require further tweaking to suit individual specifications.